# fetching records takes a long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a table in Oracle with more than 100,869,984 records in it. when I run this query in `Oracle SQL Developer` it takes one minute which is quite a long time for  fetching just one record

```
select 
    * 
from
    E_MW_01MIN_MIT
Where  
    replace(substr(TO_CHAR (DBTM, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 1, 5), '00:00', '24:00') = '11:01'
    and TO_CHAR (DBTM, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '07-05-1396'  
    and AVNR = 2075;
```

Sometimes after running for the first time, it will be faster fetching data, it reduces to 5 seconds.
I have an index on DBTM and AVNR both.

How can I find out what is the problem?

Comment: you are trying to use functions in the WHERE clause and it makes the query slow. Try to have separate persisted calculated column for this where clause.

Comment: You could try to change the order of the where statement. Check _AVNR_ first.

Comment: why dont you ake use of paging , means you fetch half record in one query and half in second query , by using rownumber i.e. select * from table where rownumber >0 and rownumber < 1000 and second query select * from table wehre rownumber > 1000 and rownumber < 2000

Comment: The faster run on a second execution could be due to caching.  Without seeing what indexes are present it is not certain, but at a glance, I'd read this the same as @VenkataramanR -- the functions in the where clause trigger a full scan instead of index access.  You might consider function-based indexes https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505

Comment: @PranayRana - As the OP's problem is the length of time required to retrieve one record, I'm really not sure why you think paging might help.

Comment: *How can I find out what is the problem?* Examine the execution plan and SQL Monitor report, see where the resources are being consumed and look for ways to tune the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the nls_date_format to what I want

```
  alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

After That I omitted the unnecessary function in Select Command. and then the answered appeared in less that 0.1 second

Answer (score 0):

Returning just one record is irrelevant. It depends on how many rows or index entries need to be scanned to find it.

Assuming there is an index on DBTM, it should be much faster to search for a range of date times. For example if you are looking at anything that happenned at '07-05-1396 11:01' then you would look for >= '07-05-1396 11:01' and < '07-05-1396 11:02'. Just put your conversions on the literal rather than the database column to make sure that the index on the column can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in timing is probably due to caching.

I would rewrite the `where` as:

```
Where replace(substr(TO_CHAR(DBTM, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 1, 5), '00:00', '24:00') = '11:01' and
      dbtm >= date '1396-05-07' and
      dbtm < date '1396-05-08' and 
      avnr = 2075
```

Then I would suggest a composite index on `(avnr, dbtm)`.

I'm not sure what the first condition is trying to do, but this index will filter based on the rest of the conditions, which should speed up the query.